# How can I add reminders into mobile device calendar using Java script?

Tags: javascript

How can I add reminders into mobile device calendar using Java script? I want to use this script in a Phonegap Application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Phonegap calendar plugin to add events: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Calendar-PhoneGap-Plugin

e.g.

```
window.plugins.calendar.createEvent(title,eventLocation,notes,startDate,endDate,success,error);
```

You can then add reminders to events:

```
  // or to add a reminder, make it recurring, change the calendar, or the url, use this one:
var filterOptions = window.plugins.calendar.getCalendarOptions(); // or {} or null for the defaults
filterOptions.calendarName = "Bla"; // iOS only
filterOptions.id = "D9B1D85E-1182-458D-B110-4425F17819F1"; // iOS only, get it from createEventWithOptions (if not found, we try matching against title, etc)
var newOptions = window.plugins.calendar.getCalendarOptions();
newOptions.calendaName = "New Bla"; // make sure this calendar exists before moving the event to it
// not passing in reminders will wipe them from the event. To wipe the default first reminder (60), set it to null.
newOptions.firstReminderMinutes = 120;
  window.plugins.calendar.modifyEventWithOptions(title,eventLocation,notes,startDate,endDate,newTitle,eventLocation,notes,startDate,endDate,filterOptions,newOptions,success,error);
```